# Java File only seen and written to by program

Tags: java, file-permissions

I am creating a program for a school class that will access Twitter and allow them to do many of the normal functions (post, send/receive messages, view timeline...). I am implementing this using [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) and so as not to have the client go through the authorization process everytime they log in I am saving their authorization tokens to a file. As this is a big security risk, I am wondering how to set it so that the file they are being written to can only be read and written by the program. Or if there is a much better way to implement this functionality I am all ears.

Comment: Why not just let them access twitter? :-)

Comment: No matter how you store the tokens. They can be reverse engineered. :)

Comment: @Thihara - Made it a desktop version (Also needed an idea and I've never done much GUI work so sounded fun)

Comment: Keep the token in memory and terminate when the application closes. They can re authenticate when they run it again...

Comment: @Thihara - The problem is that they then have to go to a URL then enter the pin each time was hoping for more of a "remember me / password" thing, or is the reason that those mainly work due to encryption on the files?

Comment: Then you need to encrypt the token in a way that your application can decrypt it back... Of course this again leads you in a circle since you need to keep the encryption key secure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you stored the token in a file on localhost, anyone who can access the laptop will be able to retrieve the file.

1/ We can set NTFS permission for the file so only the intended user can access the file.  However, in Windows it is not possible to restrict access to a file to a certain program. (Exception is with antivirus when it is able to lock the virus vault - If you want to do this you must keep your program constantly running in background to maintain a lock on the file)

2/ An easier way is to encrypt the token so that it can only be decrypted correctly using your program and on the installed machine. 
For instance:  token = myEncryption(user's authen info, my encrypt key, localhost unique ID ) 
Using this method, you can keep the token safe from being stolen. If someone steals the file, they can not use it on other laptop, nor can they run it with other program.
   Anyway, the fact is: there is no absolute safety method.  "all key can be broken" :)

Cheers.

Comment: "all key can be broken" ha sadly yeah, figured though I should attempt to make it slightly harder then opening up a file :), Ill most likely be going a simple encryption route but thanks for the help!